# display form above a background color with using CSS3

Tags: css

Hi I was wondering how to get a form to display above a background color and may be nudge it out a bit with with the property 'position: relative' and set it to position with top or left or can i use 'z-index' to take form out of stacking or something else please let me know?

heres something I tried to do...

```
            <div class = "background">
             <form action = "" method = "" class = "form">
            <input type = "text">
             </form>
             </div>

        CSS3 CODE...

            .background {
                background:color: red;
                z-index: 100;
            }

           .form 
              {
              background-color: blue;
              position: relative;
              float: right;
              z-index: 200;
            }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Can you clarify? What is "nudge it out a bit"? Anyway, the source you have here has problems: 1) the css has an error; `background:color` should be `background-color`. 2) Since the form is floating and there's nothing else in the div, the height of effectively collapses to 0, so you won't get to see its background color anyway. 3) Also, since the input is the only item in the form, it takes up all its space and you won't even see the form's background.

Comment: Did you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/am5wqp14/), where the form is offset slightly from the div, making it look like it's on top of it rather than in it?